# Problem upgrading a chroot for FAT Clients (ltsp, edubuntu, and 14.04)

Tags: chroot, edubuntu, ltsp

I have an edubuntu server. After I got the fat client image built, I followed the instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuLTSP/ThinClientHowtoNAT so that the clients could have access to the internet, which seems to be working fine.

When I want to upgrade the chroot for the clients, I open up a terminal and run:

```
sudo chroot /opt/ltsp/i386
mount -t proc proc /proc
```

Now when I try to run "apt-get update" I get an error about not being about to reach the repositories. so I tried to ping google.com, ubuntu.com, etc, and it cannot look up the domain names. I can ping the ltsp server just fine, and again, when I am actually logged on to a client, everything on the internet seems to work fine.

Why can't I see anything on the internet when I'm chrooted in to the client image any more?

Comment: Is it just a name resolution problem?  That is, can you ping remote sites by ip address (e.g., `ping 8.8.8.8`)?  If this works, it just means you need to configure `/etc/resolv.conf` in your `chroot` environment.

Comment: That did it, thanks! I'll put exactly everything I did into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on larsks's comment, here's what I did.

```
sudo chroot /opt/ltsp/i386
mount -t proc proc /proc
rm -f /etc/resolv.conf  
nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

And the content of the new resolv.conf (I'm using OpenDNS's family shield nameservers - it's in an elementary school lab) is:

```
nameserver 208.67.222.123
nameserver 208.67.220.123
```

Save the file, exit out of chroot, then run

```
sudo ltsp-update-image
```

which I didn't know if I would need or not. However, it all is working, now.